# CSS grid layout with independent scrolling boxes

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a basic layout comprised of a top nav, side nav, and content. The content and side nav are both taller than the page. I want to make sure there is no scrollbar for the entire page, but the side nav and content divs both have their own independent scroll bars for viewing the content. I have tried various combinations of the CSS overflow property but can't get it to work. Note the `position: relative;` on the nav to ensure that it's shadow is on top of the side nav.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .box-shadow-z1 {
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
          0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      }
      .box-shadow-z3 {
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
          0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 300px auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-template-areas:
          "nav nav"
          "side-nav content";
      }
      nav {
        grid-area: nav;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative; /* this is to ensure the shadow is on top */
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
      }
      #side-nav {
        grid-area: side-nav;
        background-color: white;
        height: 1000px;
      }
      #content {
        grid-area: content;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      #actual-content {
        background-color: white;
        height: 2000px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="box-shadow-z3"></nav>
    <div id="side-nav" class="box-shadow-z1">side nav</div>
    <div id="content"><div id="actual-content" class="box-shadow-z1">content</div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following CSS:

```
body {
   height: 100vh;
}

#side-nav,
#content {
   max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Used height concept to achieve that thing: you use 100vh to get the 100% of the height and you subtract 200px, which is the nav height you defined.

Here's a working Codepen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/MWaKMbE

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution by using Alessio's answer to use calc to calculate the height. I also needed to ensure that the side nav was in a wrapper so that the `overflow-y: scroll;` can be applied to contents. Here is a full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .box-shadow-z1 {
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
          0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      }
      .box-shadow-z3 {
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
          0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 300px auto;
        grid-template-rows: 100px calc(100vh - 100px);
        grid-template-areas:
          "nav nav"
          "side-nav content";
      }
      nav {
        grid-area: nav;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative; /* this is to ensure the shadow is on top */
        width: 100%;
      }
      #side-nav {
        grid-area: side-nav;
        background-color: white;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      #side-nav-content {
        height: 10000px;
      }
      #content {
        grid-area: content;
        padding: 20px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      #actual-content {
        background-color: white;
        height: 2000px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="box-shadow-z3"></nav>
    <div id="side-nav" class="box-shadow-z1"><div id="side-nav-content">side nav</div></div>
    <div id="content"><div id="actual-content" class="box-shadow-z1">content</div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```